# What do Option-Up Arrow and Option-Down Arrow do in the Finder?

Tags: keyboard, finder

Okay, I have no idea how I stumbled onto this and can't recall encountering it before (and I've been using Macs for a LOONNGG time, but what does combining the Option key with the up/down arrow keys do in the Finder (Mac OSX 12.1 Monterey)?

I thought it was cycling through open windows (nope), then I thought it was "walking" back through windows that have been closed (nope, I don't think), maybe it was going up/down the hierarchy (nope, that's what CMD-up/down does). I can have a single Finder window open, hit Option-Up, get some rando window, close it, do the same keystroke again, and get a completely different and unrelated, and equally random window.

Comment: For Me, in finder, option up takes me to the last item in that finder window

Comment: Odd - seems to be something to do with Recent Folders, but not all that simple. If I step up a few times i get folders I opened 'a while back' in no [articular order, except the order is repeatable if I close them all again. Opt down steps through these already opened folders in the opposite direction. Not a clue what it's actually thinking;) [BTW, this is on Mojave, so it's not a new behaviour]

Comment: Which Finder view do you use: icons, list, column, gallery?

Comment: @nohillside - not seeing any significant change in behaviour whichever view I'm using, nor which folder I start in. I haven't gone beyond maybe 10 folders sprung up by this method, but I'm seeing the same ones each time in something nearly like a predictable order.

Comment: @Tetsujin Interesting. In Column view, Opt-Up/Down jumps to the first/last entry in the current folder for me (running Monterey)

Comment: I hadn't tested column… but no change - still springs up one of these 'odd' list of folders. Doesn't navigate the current view at all.

Comment: **Ahhh…** Default Folder X. In the Shortcuts list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pre-emptive guess - you have Default Folder X installed.

It's in the default shortcuts list…

[image]

I'm not sure I fully agree with its definition of 'Recents' - mine didn't quite match the Finder's list [though it does now I've been playing with it for half an hour, of course]
Another guess - it's using its own Recents list of folders I've accessed through Open/Save dialogs rather than via Finder itself.

An app I've been using maybe two decades,  since before it had the 'X', & I *still* haven't explored its full potential - I really should, one day ;)

Comment: (facepalm) You nailed it. The folders were all “familiar” in that I’ve accessed them within the last few days, but they weren’t in the right order. Maybe it does some kind of clever “you visit this folder often, and you visited it recently, maybe this is the one you want?”

Anyway, thanks for clearing up that mystery. It wasn’t like it was interfering with getting something done, it just bugged me. :)